# How to assign values to methods that are included in class via a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

```
module MyModule
   def method1
     @my_value
   end

   def method2
     "#{method1} is another method"
   end
end

class MyClass
    include MyModule
    @my_value = 'Method1' 
end

puts MyClass.new().method2
>>   is another method
```

How can I get the value assigned to my methods that I included into my class? As you can see @my_value is nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
module MyModule
  def set_my_value(val)
    define_method :my_value do
      val
    end
  end

  def method1
    my_value
  end

  def method2
    "#{method1} is another method"
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule
  extend MyModule
  @my_value = 'Method1'
  set_my_value 'Method1'
end
```

you can make it like this, rails uses this way heavily, and when you include a module to a class it will be a parent in the inheritance hierarchy of this class so you can't access it's instance variable directly as you did (in class body) to access it you need to do from an inside method

```
module MyModule
  def method1
    @my_value
  end

  def method2
    "#{method1} is another method"
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyModule
  def initialize
    @my_value = 'Method1'
  end
end

puts MyClass.new().method2
```

what you defined in your code was a class instance variable and it's not the instance variable you were trying to modify